# Browser-based GUI in a stand-alone environment

Tags: php, user-interface, web-applications

I have an idea for creating a browser-based GUI frontend for a stand-alone desktop application. Suppose that the computer already has the CUI binary executable as the backend, if I

1. Install PHP and run its built-in http server,
2. Utilize ajax and PHP's exec() function to execute the binary on a local filesystem

then... it seems that I can build a GUI frontend for a stand-alone computer, without installing any dedicated GUI framework.

Here is what I tested with the git command (requires a php on your system)
https://github.com/nyankosoft/php-exec-localhost

The reason why I even consider this esoteric and bizarre option is that we have a plan to deploy the application on a real server in the future, but this is a long-term goal. In the meantime, most of the users of the application are currently content with the desktop app and they just want a GUI frontend that runs on their local machines. It seems that this method is more likely to help the transition to a web-based service later than a cross-platform GUI toolkit such as Qt. I also have heard about some modern GUI frameworks such as React Native and Electron, but I'm not familiar with these. So, could the approach above be viable? or is there a better way?

Comment: Its a little unclear what your trying to do, getting text responses are trivial as your seeing (though your implementation is insecure), you wont be able to get rendered desktop display like VNC etc with just php. Your be better off simply installing VNC/RDP or if you want just text, then something like shellinabox.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, there is another solution for your goal.
In VB you can make a basic browser and basically set it to a site - so the user has no other options.
http://www.vbasic.net/how-to-create-a-basic-web-browser-in-visual-basic/

I think the browser will be whatever is the highest version of IE on the persons machine - have to give it a go.

The make your php web application as you see fit.
Users will be using the application without knowing they are on the intranet.

Pretty soon, remove the vb application - use whatever browser.